# string method doesn't work even if I pass it to a parameter python

Tags: python, string, replace

Hello I am a C# programmer but I think it's good to learn python too so I am learning python I have this code

```
def disemvowel(string_):
    for n in string_:
        if(n is 'a' or 'e' or 'u' or 'o' or 'i'):
            string_ = string_.replace('n' , '')
    return string_
print(disemvowel('Hello'))
```

I declared a function that removes vowels from a string I searched its problems but I couldn't find anything I even passed the return value of the replace function to string and then pass it what is my code problem ?
thanks for you answers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`is` is used to compare the ID's. In your case, it is not necessary that n and "a" have same memory location. You can change it to `==` to compare the VALUES. If the value of n is "a" then n=="a" should return `True`. `is` will return `True` when the location of both will be same. It will return `False` even if the value is correct. Or you can use `in` as well. `in` will return `True` if the variable in present in a string or iterable datatypes. Your code would be:

1. using `==`:

```
def disemvowel(string_):
    for n in string_:
        if n.lower()=="a" or n.lower()=="e" or n.lower()=="i" or n.lower()=="o" or n.lower()=="u":
            string_ = string_.replace(n,'')
    return string_
print(disemvowel('Hello'))
```

2. using `in`

```
def disemvowel(string_):
    for n in string_:
        if n.lower() in ["a","e","i","o","u"]:
            string_ = string_.replace(n,'')
    return string_
print(disemvowel('Hello'))
```

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
def disemvowel(string_):
    res = ''
    for n in string_:
        if n not in ['a' , 'e',  'u' ,'o' , 'i']:
            res += n
    return res
print(disemvowel('Hello'))
```

Answer (score 0):

```
def disemvowel(string_):
    for n in string_:
        if n in 'aeiouAEIOU':
            string_ = string_.replace(n, '')
    return string_

print(disemvowel('Hello')) 


Output: 'Hll'
```

If you write `if n in 'aeiouAEIOU'` you don't have to use all the or operators.

Comment: thanks a lot but why didn't my code work?

Comment: It's because of your if statement. Your version would look like this --> if n == 'a' or n == 'e' or n == 'i' or n == 'o' or n == 'u': ...